# Multiply matrix with vector(element wise) Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am not sure on a way to put this question into a title. But will show an example on the thing that I need help in using Tensorflow.

For an example:

```
matrix_1 shape = [4,2]
matrix_2 shape  = [4,1]

matrix_1 * matrix 2
[[1,2],
 [3,4],
 [5,6],
 [7,8]]

 *

[[0.1],
 [0.2],
 [0.3],
 [0.4]]

 = [[0.1,0.2],
    [0.6,0.8],
    [1.5,1.8],
    [2.8,3.2]]
```

Is there any algorithm to achieve this?

Thank you

This is the error that I am getting from the simplified problem example above:

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 784 and 100 for 'mul_13' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [100,784], [100]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard [`tf.multiply(matrix_1, matrix_2)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/multiply) operation (or the shorthand syntax `matrix_1 * matrix_2`) will perform exactly the computation that you want on `matrix_1` and `matrix_2`.

However, it looks like the error message you are seeing is because `matrix_2` has shape `[100]`, whereas it must be `[100, 1]` to get the [elementwise broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) behavior. Use [`tf.reshape(matrix_2, [100, 1])`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) or [`tf.expand_dims(matrix_2, 1)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) to convert it to the correct shape.